# nested if loop in splunk

Tags: if-statement, nested-loops, splunk, splunk-query

I would like to write in splunk a nested if loop:
**What I want to achieve**

> ```
> if buyer_from_France: 
>    do eval percentage_fruits
>    if percentage_fruits> 10:
>         do summation
>         if summation>20:
>                    total_price
>                    if total_price>$50:
>                               do(trigger bonus coupon)
> ```

My current code (that works):

```
> | eventstats sum(buyers_fruits) AS total_buyers_fruits by location
> | stats sum(fruits) as buyers_fruits by location buyers 
> | eval percentage_fruits=fruits_bought/fruits_sold 
> | table fruits_bought fruits_sold buyers
> | where percentage_fruits > 10
> | sort - percentage_fruits
```

How do I complete the syntax/expression for the 2nd (summation) and consequently, 3rd (total price), 4th if-loop (trigger)?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to do a nested if loop. For instance, if (A happens: (if B happens: (if C happens: do D)))

Comment: For instance, if (A happens: (if B happens: (if C happens: do D))). Will like to get the innermost contents and manipulate "D functions" with them. I know python can, but cant find the syntax for splunk nested if.

Comment: I see what you're asking - but you haven't said what you're trying to *do* :) SPL doesn't do "loops". A close [enough] analog is that each line in SPL is *similar* to a single command in bash (hence the pipe separator between commands). IOW, SPL is purely linear in processing. Use a multi-condition `eval..if` like I've put in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPL doesn't do "loops". A close [enough] analog is that each line in SPL is *similar* to a single command in bash (hence the pipe separator between commands). IOW, SPL is purely linear in processing. Use a multi-condition [`eval..if`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| eval myfield=if(match(fieldA,"someval") AND !match(fieldC,"notthis"),"all true","else val")
```

Or like this:

```
| eval myfield=if(match(fieldA,"someval"),if(match(fieldB,"otherval"),"matched A&B",if(!match(fieldC,"notthis"),"not A & not C","else val")))
```

If you can explain your use case/end goal better, we can probably provide better direction

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for replying late; this does the job